# I am trying to match certain barcode info and exclude the special character percentage in Regex C#

Tags: regex

The OCR technique reads and fills this data: %BEENAT191219091-651551%1.

And I want to use Regex to make it match and exclude the special characters.

This should be the result: BEENAT191219091.

This is what i've tried:

```
 Barcode: %BEENAT191219091-651551%1 

 Result: BEENAT191219091-651551

 With this Regex: ^(?!%)\w+\d+\W\d+(?!%)$
```

And

```
 Barcode: %BEENAT191219091-651551%1 

 Result: BEENAT191219091

 With this Regex: ^(?!%)\w+\d+$
```

But I can't get it to work sadly it doesn't match at all.

Feedback is much appreciated!

```
When I use the following Regex it does match the entire string:
^\W\w+\d+\W\d+\W\d+$ -> Result: %BEENAT191219091-651551%1
```

> But can I make it match this string: %BEENAT191219091-651551%1
>
> And show only this or match on those parts alone?: BEENAT191219091-651551

Comment: Could you please format properly your question?

Comment: My bad. I tried to format it more properly I will try to make it as clean and neat as possible.

Comment: Use `[^\w-]` to *replace* with an empty string. You can't match disjoint pieces of text within one match operation.

Comment: Thank you a lot Wiktor Stribizew! This actually helped me a lot and I gained insight on more things while testing!